# How Ajax enables a Javascript string to be passed to php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I've been learning Ajax and now I'm wondering how it allows a string from Javascript to be passed to php.

It was said before that the problem with passing Javascript to PHP is that the PHP code gets run first, and then the Javascript gets run. So when Javascript generates a string it's already too late.

Does this mean that Ajax allows PHP code to be run after Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what they're getting at:

Before Ajax -- specifically, before [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) came along -- a single web page was served as a single page load. If it was a PHP-generated page incorporating Javascript, the browser would request the page, PHP would generate the page (including Javascript code, includes, fragments of script on the page, etc.), would send the page to the browser, and the browser would display it. So, the PHP happened up-front. Until the next page load -- when the *entire* page was refreshed from scratch -- PHP wasn't involved again.

After the advent of [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest), which helped put the "X" in "AJAX", as it was back then, you had another option. Once the page was loaded, your Javascript could make requests "behind the scenes" of the page, to request more information from the server, without reloading the page. In effect, the loaded page could cause more PHP to be run on the server, and display the results.

So, if you're considering a single page load from a PHP-based website, that is (sort of) what Ajax means; without it, you get a single PHP page-build that's delivered and then your Javascript has to run on that result alone. With Ajax, you can make further requests to your server and throw the results out onto the existing page without a full page load.

Answer (score 0):

The php interpreter sitting on the server is basically interprets whatever php script into (usually) HTML page.

That's why you can never "pass" javascript variable into php as to the interpreter, your javascript is just yet another string, without any special meaning. Your javascript is run by your browser and doesn't even aware that it was being produced by PHP.

I believe that's what it means by "too late".

Answer (score 0):

You should know, that Javascript is always (except Node.js) Client-Side.
PHP is a Server-Side language.

You can't pass Javascript variables to PHP - at least not at the Pageload.

What you *can* do is doing a AJAX-Request after the Page is laoded to send something to PHP.
With the Response of that call you can replace some other things on the current requested Page.

Answer (score 0):

**No** it does not mean that "Ajax allows PHP code to be run after Javascript". AJAX is a *new request* to the server and it allows you to manipulate with the server's *response*. You can observe this by coping the url to which AJAX request is being made and pasting it into the browser.
So basically when you open a web site with the browser, you send a request and any AJAX call is also a request, but done in a background, so you cannot see it directly. You can use for example firebug or other developer's tool to see what happens behind the scenes. It has nothing to do with the scripts executions orders.